# Highlighting columns on a WPF DataGrid as mouse moves

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid, .net-4.0, effects

I wish to highlight the columns on a WPF datagrid as the mouse moves. Some of the problems I face are:

- Getting the coordinates of columns to test for when the mouse is over them
- Changing the background color of a column

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about updating the style for the DataGridCell and defining an "IsMouseOver" trigger in it?  Something like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="{x:Type DataGridCell}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

**EDIT**:

Below is a solution that:  1)  highlights the currently hovered cell, 2) highlights the entire row, and 3) highlights the entire column.  I just coded this up quickly and haven't tested it thoroughly so you might encounter some issues.  But anyway, this should give you an idea on how they can be done.

My solution for highlighting the entire column involves the use of two attached properties that were being assigned to the DataGridCell when the mouse is over it.  Just check it out and see if it works for you.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DataGrid x:Name="dg" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="{x:Type DataGridCell}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="local:DataGridBehavior.IsCellHighlighted" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="local:DataGridBehavior.HighlightColumn" Value="True"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
    </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

DataGridBehavior class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class DataGridBehavior : DependencyObject
    {

        public static bool GetHighlightColumn(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(HighlightColumnProperty);
        }

        public static void SetHighlightColumn(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(HighlightColumnProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for HighlightColumn.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HighlightColumnProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HighlightColumn", typeof(bool), 
            typeof(DataGridBehavior), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, OnHighlightColumnPropertyChanged));



        public static bool GetIsCellHighlighted(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsCellHighlightedProperty);
        }

        public static void SetIsCellHighlighted(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(IsCellHighlightedProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsCellHighlighted.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCellHighlightedProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsCellHighlighted", typeof(bool), typeof(DataGridBehavior), 
            new UIPropertyMetadata(false));



        private static void OnHighlightColumnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.NewValue);
            DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;

            if (cell != null) 
            {
                DataGrid dg = GetDataGridFromCell(cell);
                DataGridColumn column = cell.Column;

                for (int i = 0; i < dg.Items.Count; i++) 
                {
                    DataGridRow row = dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as DataGridRow;
                    DataGridCell currentCell = GetCell(row, column);
                    if (currentCell != null)
                    {
                        currentCell.SetValue(DataGridBehavior.IsCellHighlightedProperty, e.NewValue);
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        private static DataGrid GetDataGridFromCell(DataGridCell cell)
        { 
            DataGrid retVal = null;
            FrameworkElement fe = cell;
            while ((retVal == null) && (fe != null))
            {
                if (fe is DataGrid)
                    retVal = fe as DataGrid;
                else
                    fe = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(fe) as FrameworkElement;
            }
            return retVal;
        }

        private static DataGridCell GetCell(DataGridRow row, DataGridColumn column) 
        {
            DataGridCell retVal = null;
            DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);
            if (presenter != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < presenter.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    DataGridCell cell = presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as DataGridCell;
                    if ((cell != null) && (cell.Column == column))
                    {
                        retVal = cell;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return retVal;
        }

        private static T GetVisualChild<T>(Visual parent) where T : Visual
        {
            T child = default(T);
            int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
            for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
            {
                Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                child = v as T;
                if (child == null)
                {
                    child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
                }
                if (child != null)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return child;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great! But it only works for a single cell. How could I make it to work for all cells in the column? In fact, I also wish to highlight all the cells in the same row as the highlighted cell.

Comment: Thank you for your effort! It works, however the performance is slow and I think I will just quit the whole endeavor of highlighting cells :(

Comment: Yeah, I figured that will be an issue with this solution when there are lots of items on the grid.  And unfortunately, highlighting an entire column isn't as trivial as highlighting a cell or row because of the way the DataGrid is designed.  So, sorry it didn't work well enough for you.